# How to Freeze a postgres table that uses a UUID field with peewee?

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

I'm trying to freeze a postgres table that has a UUID primary key like so:

```
data_set = DataSet(conn)
data_set["map_sources"].freeze(filename="frozen_gis.json", format="json")
```

I'm getting this exception that UUID('some-uuid') is not JSON serializeable.
Since I'm not using the Model of the table to perform this action (which I should be able to, but it seems freeze() is not available to it), I can't rely on changing the `python_value` method to use an inheriting class from UUIDField and stringify it in that method.

What am I missing here? How can I serialize this field?

Comment: This is fixed in 586797a9d888aba923d974d64bf8f160a6d5dc38 - I added UUID types to be string-ified when serialized to JSON.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I want to a solution until you release the next tag, I need to somehow override DataSet's JSONExporter?

Comment: Yes, or just use master for now